# From sessions to minute by minute summary

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which has viewing sessions with start and end timestamps, and i would like to create a minute-by-minute summary showing the number of people in each minute.
A simplified version of my data looks like this:

```
db<-data.frame(id=1:4, start=c(1,1,2,4), end=c(3,4,5,6))
```

And i would like something like this:

```
min1to2 = 2,
min2to3 = 3,
min3to4 = 2,
min4to5 = 2,
min5to6 = 1
```

In reality my dataset is very large (about 6Gb) and the level of granularity is the second, so a timestamp would look like this: `"2017-04-01 09:01:26"`.  Ideally I'd like to use dplyr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't min1to2 = 2?

Comment: With data.table `foverlaps(setDT(db), setkey(data.table(start = 1:5, end = 2:6)))[,.N , by=.(start, end)]` though this gives different results since you use undisclosed rules for counting.

Comment: thanks very much @Frank, that should do the trick! is there a way to specify that my sessions would be formulated as semi-open intervals like this: [start, end[

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that too, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Using `data.table` & `cut`: `setDT(db)[, .(num = start:end), id][, grp := cut(num, 1:7, right = FALSE)][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package based on my comment:

```
# create the data as in the question
library(data.table)
db <- data.table(id=1:4, start=c(1,1,2,4), end=c(3,4,5,6))

# convert the 'start' & 'end' columns into real minute data
set.seed(1)
db[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.POSIXct(paste0('2017-05-31 15:',x,':',sample(15:45,4)), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ), .SDcols = 2:3]
```

This results in the following data.table:

> ```
>    id               start                 end
> 1:  1 2017-05-31 15:01:23 2017-05-31 15:03:21
> 2:  2 2017-05-31 15:01:26 2017-05-31 15:04:41
> 3:  3 2017-05-31 15:02:31 2017-05-31 15:05:42
> 4:  4 2017-05-31 15:04:40 2017-05-31 15:06:33
> ```

Now, the following code:

```
db[, .(times = seq(as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(start)/60)*60, origin = '1970-01-01'),
                   as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(end)/60)*60, origin = '1970-01-01'), 'min')), id
   ][, .N, times][]
```

gives:

> ```
>                  times N
> 1: 2017-05-31 15:01:00 2
> 2: 2017-05-31 15:02:00 3
> 3: 2017-05-31 15:03:00 3
> 4: 2017-05-31 15:04:00 3
> 5: 2017-05-31 15:05:00 2
> 6: 2017-05-31 15:06:00 1
> ```

Comment: i think that's almost there... what i would need is a cut that would create segments that open on both sides.  Otherwise the interval min3to4 includes the last id which starts on min4.

Comment: @chrisjacques see the update; it should be correct now; note that I changed the data by including seconds; min3to4 include 3 observations with the new example data; HTH